# TKinter window not showing in program with .after() statement

Tags: python, tkinter, screen-scraping

I am trying to do a self-updating script to display a table with some data I am **scraping** from a few websites. The data is scraped, loaded, formatted and then it should be displayed in a table format in TKinter. However, when I make it self-refreshing with root.after() the window does not appear at all. I know the program is running, because I see output in the terminal, but nothing comes up as a TKwindow. Is there something I am missing from .after()'s behaviour? Would it not run when there are a lot of lines?

I tried just commenting the .after() part and the script would execute completely and then show me the window. I also never entered the Else statement, which is fine, but for some reason the code would not work even with just the If statement.

Below is the code I used

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry("1080x1080")

def calculations():

    Scraping_and_writing_in_files()
    
    final_result = File_format_pandas()
    

    if len(final_result.index) == 0:
        label = Label(root, text = "There are no hits")
        label.pack()
        print("I am in the if statement - no hits found")
    else:
        print("I am in the else statement") # I was never in the Else statement so you can ignore the code below 
        #Create a main frame 

        main_frame = Frame(root)
        main_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        #Create a canvas 

        my_canvas = Canvas(main_frame)
        my_canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        #Add scrollbar 

        my_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(main_frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=my_canvas.yview)
        my_scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

        #Configure scrollbar

        my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar.set)
        my_canvas.bind('<Configure>',lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion = my_canvas.bbox("all")))


        def _on_mouse_wheel(event):
            my_canvas.yview_scroll(-1 * int((event.delta / 120)), "units")

        my_canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", _on_mouse_wheel)


        #Create another frame in the canvas

        second_frame = Frame(my_canvas)

        #Add that new frame to a window in the canvas 

        my_canvas.create_window((0,0), window=second_frame, anchor = "nw")

        initial_entries1 = Entry(second_frame,font=("Helvetica", 12),bd=0,width=30)
        initial_entries1.insert(0, "Match Name")
        initial_entries1.config(state = "readonly")
        initial_entries1.grid(row=0, column=0)

        initial_entries2 = Entry(second_frame,font=("Helvetica", 12),bd=0,width=30)
        initial_entries2.insert(0, "Result for T1")
        initial_entries2.config(state = "readonly")
        initial_entries2.grid(row=0, column=1)

        initial_entries3 = Entry(second_frame,font=("Helvetica", 12),bd=0,width=30)
        initial_entries3.insert(0, "Result for Draw")
        initial_entries3.config(state = "readonly")
        initial_entries3.grid(row=0, column=2)

        initial_entries3 = Entry(second_frame,font=("Helvetica", 12),bd=0,width=30)
        initial_entries3.insert(0, "Result for T2")
        initial_entries3.config(state = "readonly")
        initial_entries3.grid(row=0, column=3)


        for thing in range(len(final_result.index)):

            match_name = Entry(second_frame, font=("Helvetica", 10),bd=0,width=30)
            match_name.insert(0, final_result['Match name'].iloc[thing])
            match_name.config(state = "readonly")
            match_name.grid(row=thing+1, column=0)

            result_t1 = Entry(second_frame, font=("Helvetica", 10),bd=0,width=15)
            result_t1.insert(0, final_result['Difference Team 1 For'].iloc[thing])
            if float(final_result['Difference Team 1 For'].iloc[thing]) > 0:
                result_t1.config(state = "readonly")
            result_t1.grid(row=thing+1, column=1)

            result_t2 = Entry(second_frame, font=("helvetica", 10), bd=0, width=15)
            result_t2.insert(0, final_result['Difference Team 2 For'].iloc[thing])
            if float(final_result['Difference Team 2 For'].iloc[thing])>0:
                result_t2.config(state = "readonly")
            result_t2.grid(row=thing+1, column=3)

            result_draw = Entry(second_frame, font=("helvetica", 10), bd=0, width=15)
            result_draw.insert(0, final_result['Difference Draw For'].iloc[thing])
            if float(final_result['Difference Draw For'].iloc[thing]) > 0:
                result_draw.config(state = "readonly")
            result_draw.grid(row=thing+1, column=2)
    
        root.after(2000, main_frame.destroy())

        #     label1 = Label(second_frame, text="Google Hyperlink", fg="blue", cursor="hand2")
        #     label1.pack()
        #     label1.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: callback("http://www.google.com"))


    root.after(1000, calculations())

calculations()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `root.after(2000, main_frame.destroy())` calls `.destroy()` *right now*, and two seconds later does nothing (because `.destroy()` didn't return anything).  You don't want those parentheses after the method name, you want to pass the method itself to `.after()`.

Comment: Yes, you are both right. That was the issue, Thanks!

Comment: @Sujay That isn't going to work :D (you missed the brackets). If it's in a `lambda`, you need the brackets.

Comment: Oh yeah!!  Thanks @TheLizzard

Comment: ```root.after(2000,lambda: main_frame.destroy())```

Answer (score 0):

In the after method no parentheses are needed, since they call the function immediately and will use whatever it returns as callback after the delay. Thank you Jasonharper and Sujay.

root.after(1000, calculations()) => should be root.after(1000, calculations)